# How do I centre all page titles site wide without centring post titles or site title?

Tags: pages

I'd like page titles centred site wide especially for landing pages.

Is this possible without centring posts titles and everything else on the site?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is really not feasible to answer. It will vary heavily from theme to theme. Please elaborate.

Comment: This would be done in the style sheet, do you have a link to the site in question?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like

```
$the_post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

switch ( $the_post_type ) {
    case 'page':
        // you'll need something else to distinguish "landing" pages from normal ones
        // which would allow you to then set a flag for it 

        if ( $some_condition ) $landing_page = true; 

        if ( $landing_page) {
            // display your title with the class that'll centre it
        }
    break;

    case 'post':
    case default:
        // display your title with the normal class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in your theme's style.css

```
h1.page-title {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then make sure that in your theme's page.php you have one instance of the h1 tag with a 'page-title' class on it. For example:

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```